# Trace TraceEventType and Category

Tags: .net, trace, system.diagnostics

How do Trace an entry with both a category and a TraceEventType?

That is, I can trace a message with a category:

```
Trace.WriteLine("hello", "MyCategory");
```

And I can trace a warning:

```
Trace.TraceWarning("uh oh");
```

but how do I trace a warning with a category?

I want this to apply to all listeners...I don't want to have to select a specific listener.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as far as I can see;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.tracewarning.aspx